# Como fazer divisões no processo de desenvolvimento de software

Tags: gerenciamento-de-projetos

Temos um projeto todo arquitetado no papel, desenhos, esboços, o que cada parte do sistema vai fazer, mas como podemos gerenciar a equipe, definir por qual parte do código começar? Pelo feed de noticias ou pelo login? Nossa equipe, de 3 desenvolvedores está tendo dificuldade com isso já que somos todos leigos, e não consegui achar quase nada sobre isso na internet. Obrigado.

Mais informações sobre o projeto: Somos 2 programadores de android/java, e um de banco de dados, sem muita experiência claro. Temos que desenvolver um aplicativo em que será preciso login e senha, e um feed de noticias onde aparecerá os amigos que o usuário segue, e também terei de inserir informações do google maps, e tudo isso salvo dentro do banco de dados claro. O que a gente tem dificuldade, é por onde começar, programação? design? Qual parte da programação? Primeiro o maps, ou primeiro o login? Primeiro o feed? Não temos prazo, por isso ta mais tranquilo. Se alguém puder dar algum norte, ou material para ajudar.

Itens: 
• Login
• Feed de Noticias
• Botão de gostei
• Google maps
• Compartilhar com facebook

Comment: Talvez seja melhor você delinear a arquitetura do projeto aqui. É só feed e login, não né?

Comment: Por favor edite sua questão explanando sobre o projeto? sem saber qual a realidade do projeto, itens a serem feitos, tempo fica meio complicado opinar ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acho que podem começar respondendo algumas perguntas:

1. Quais são todas as tarefas necessárias para o projeto (incluindo componentes do sistema, design, aquisição de software, hardware ou qualquer recurso)?
2. Quais destas tarefas dependem de outras?
3. Quanto tempo/esforço vai ser necessário para concluir cada tarefa?
4. Qual é o nível de complexidade de cada tarefa?
5. Quais tarefas possuem riscos de se tornarem mais custosas ao longo do projeto? Por exemplo, um software em promoção ficará mais caro se for comprado tarde demais, ou uma API que vocês não conhecem bem pode se revelar mais complexa do que o previsto e aumentar o tempo necessário para a tarefa.

As três primeiras questões podem ser dispostas em um [diagrama de Gantt](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagrama_de_Gantt) para facilitar a análise.

Uma vez que tiverem essas informações, acredito que ficará mais fácil decidir a prioridade de cada atividade. Tarefas que possuam mais dependentes e de maior risco em geral devem ser feitas primeiro, para não bloquear o andamento das demais, dar mais tempo de responder aos riscos antes que eles se tornem críticos e evitar surpresas no final, quando vocês estiverem com o prazo apertado.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta, valeu!

Answer (score 2):

Inicie pelo projeto, definam claramente cada uma das etapas e organize por ordem de valor, quanto mais agrega valor a aplicação maior a prioridade,Ex:(Base de dados, sistema de login, noticias etc), cada modulo deste tente quebrar mais em tarefas pequenas de 1 dia por exemplo.
da uma pesquisada em [scrum](http://desenvolvimentoagil.com.br/scrum/) que vai dar para vocês terem uma ideia melhor

Comment: Vou dar uma pesquisada sobre scrum. Valeuuu